# Hide / Remove specific text within DIV

Tags: html, css

How can I hide specific text within the div element:

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="q-a-div">
  <hr>
  <span style="color: #0000ff">
         <strong><strong>Blurred vision :</strong></strong>
       </span>
  <br> Answer Provided: Yes<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <span style="color: #0000ff">
         <strong><strong>Please provide some further details :</strong></strong>
        </span><br> Answer Provided: aaaaaaaaaaa<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <hr>
  <span style="color: #000000">
         <strong><strong><span style="color: #0000ff">If your compliant is linked to calf pain, do you have any of the following symptoms in your affected calf:</span> </strong>
  </strong>
  </span><br> Answer Provided: Not Applicable, no calf pain.<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <hr>
  <span style="color: #0000ff">
         <strong><strong>Considerable unexplained or unplanned weight loss, not linked to diet :</strong></strong>
        </span><br> Answer Provided: Yes<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <span style="color: #0000ff">
          <strong><strong>Please provide some further details :</strong></strong>
        </span><br> Answer Provided: aaaaaaaaaaa<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to hide:

- Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%
- Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%

I tried to accomplish this with CSS attributes but I can't choose attribute based on text, therefore jQuery could be an option but I would much rather stick to JavaScript as I don't have much experience adding jQuery to the Wordpress page.

Please help and many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your markup you cannot do it using CSS alone, since the text is not wrapped in an element and there is no way you can identify/access them. You can, however, use JS to simply grab the `innerHTML` of the outer div, and use `String.prototype.replace` to remove the strings:

```
const div = document.querySelector('.q-a-div');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/%(USER_COMMENTS|CORRECT_ANSWER)%/gi, '');
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.q-a-div');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/%(USER_COMMENTS|CORRECT_ANSWER)%/gi, '');
```

```html
<div class="q-a-div">
  <hr><span style="color: #0000ff"><strong><strong>Blurred vision :</strong></strong></span><br> Answer Provided: Yes<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br><span style="color: #0000ff"><strong><strong>Please provide some further details :</strong></strong></span><br>  Answer Provided: aaaaaaaaaaa<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <hr><span style="color: #000000"><strong><strong><span style="color: #0000ff">If your compliant is linked to calf pain, do you have any of the following symptoms in your affected calf:</span> </strong>
  </strong>
  </span><br> Answer Provided: Not Applicable, no calf pain.<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <hr><span style="color: #0000ff"><strong><strong>Considerable unexplained or unplanned weight loss, not linked to diet :</strong></strong></span><br> Answer Provided: Yes<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br>
  <span
    style="color: #0000ff"><strong><strong>Please provide some further details :</strong></strong>
    </span><br> Answer Provided: aaaaaaaaaaa<br> Correct Answer: %CORRECT_ANSWER%<br> Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%<br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I manage to remove the “Correct Answer and User Comments” 

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/jk3pLWH

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do

`<span style="display:none;">Comments Entered: %USER_COMMENTS%</span>`

to hide the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all elements on a HTML Page and choose the ones you want to hide depending on the text.

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    if(all[i].innerHTML == "Text you want to hide"){
        all[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```